# Rails how to make a table with composite key: (Category and Month/Year), and value: Amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to report a budget to actual table, displaying net values by month per category.
Currently I'm calculating on the fly but it's already slow with hardly more than seeded data.
I think the proper way to do this is with a composite key table. The key is the unique combination of Category and Period (Month-Year), the value is the amount.

Each transaction would trigger a callback to update this table. At report time, a user would supply the period of the report (March 2022) and it would find all rows of that period.

I think it would look something like this:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| March-2021/All Categories | $335 |
| March-2021/Food | $75 |
| March-2021/Fuel | $60 |
| March-2021/Entertainment | $200 |
| ... | ... |
| March-2022/All Categories | $49 |
| March-2022/Food | $25 |
| March-2022/Fuel | -$10 |
| March-2022/Entertainment | $34 |
| ... | ... |
| April-2022/All Categories | $58 |
| April-2022/Food | $5 |
| April-2022/Fuel | $30 |
| April-2022/Entertainment | $23 |
| April-2002/Some_New_Category | $20 |

I've read this SO question but I'd rather not blindly use a gem, and anyway it seems to involve composite 'primary' keys. (User model, and Organization model and Department model). Whereas I'm just using a Category model and a non-model period (Month-Year)

[How to implement composite primary keys in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888549/how-to-implement-composite-primary-keys-in-rails)

I can't seem to find anything about how to implement this. Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: I think it's composite indexes you need, not composite keys. Probably a key on the date and category columns

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of composite indexes. In searching about those, I realized I didn't 100% know what I wanted. So I refined, refined and refined. 
In the end, I created a "Ledger" model with three fields: category_id, date, value. And I enforced a uniqueness constraint on the category & date combination. To retrieve the records, I run Ledger.find_by(date: date, category: category).